# left join with specific conditions help please

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

am having a problem constructing a query 
here is simplified tables structure 
3 tables

```
Event [Event_id , Event_name]

Event_files [Event_id(FK) , File_id(FK)]

Uploaded_Files[File_id , File_type, File_path]
```

we mainly have 2 file types

- image = 2
- document = 4

what am trying to do is to get the events along with their images (if they have an image )
am trying to do this with this Query

```
select e.id, e.name,uf.id as file_id,uf.path  
from event e
left join event_file ef on ef.event_id = e.id
left join uploaded_file uf ON ef.file_id = uf.id
```

i know that i need to apply a condition but each time i do in the where or ON there is always problem with the Query
for example if i apply :

```
left join uploaded_file uf ON ef.file_id = uf.id AND (uf.type = 2 )
```

it will still return 2 records for the events that has both image and file one of them with file_path null .

on the other hand if i do the following :

```
where (uf.id is null OR (uf.id is not null AND uf.type=2))
```

the events with only files and no image will not be returned any more

is there is solution please ?

thanks in advance

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you are not confined to strict character limits on your questions, so please use proper grammar and punctuation so that others can follow your question more easily.

Comment: replace left join by inner join

Comment: I usually try to be as accurate as possible when posting my problems but i have limitations since English is not my mother language thanks for the pointers though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, f.file_id AS file_id, f.path
FROM event e
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT ef.event_id, uf.id AS file_id, uf.path
    FROM event_file ef
    INNER JOIN uploaded_file uf ON ef.file_id = uf.id AND uf.type = 2
) f ON f.event_id = e.id
```

This should do (untested.)
The reason you're getting the empty record is because you only specify the uf.type condition on the uploaded_file table, which imposes nothing on the left join for event_file.